check out how many resources is using opensearch-dashboard in java
I installed opensearch and opensearch-dashboard in my ubuntu vm.
When I try to find out the resources used by opensearch-dashboard with the command
top -U opensearch

i just get
Tasks: 125 total,   1 running, 124 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0,2 us,  0,1 sy,  0,0 ni, 99,6 id,  0,0 wa,  0,1 hi,  0,1 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :   3665,1 total,    869,7 free,   1745,8 used,   1049,5 buff/cache
MiB Swap:      0,0 total,      0,0 free,      0,0 used.   1606,2 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                          
  70188 opensea+  20   0 5078340   1,4g  22956 S   0,3  39,1   2:19.24 java 

and I think that that kind of infomation aggregate opensearch AND the opensearch-dashboard
how can I find out only the memory cpu and disk space used by the dashboard?

First we need the pid of opensearch dashboards, with this in your terminal:
PID=$(sudo netstat -plnt | grep 5601 | awk '{print $7}' | cut -d'/' -f1)

then, for process detail:
ps -p $PID -o pid,user,%cpu,%mem,comm,args

if you want to monitor in real time:
top -p $PID

and for the disk usage:
du -sh /usr/share/opensearch-dashboards

Notice that opensearch can launch multiple process, they may appear as node or opensearch-dashboards
